# threading in pygame

Tags: python, multithreading, pygame, subprocess

I've written a program in python and pygame on Linux. My issue is that when I call my function that dials out on a modem and then delivers a message the program pauses until the function has finished. I need a way to `subprocess` or thread the function. I'm new to python and pygame so this may be simple but everything I've tried has failed.

Also, I'm sure there's probably a more elegant way to process the sounds and pauses. The first `sleep` gives the modem time to call. The next two are for natural sounding pauses between words and sentences, and the last is to give the entire script time to deliver the message before the modem hangs up.

I'm calling the function and passing variables like this:

```
A = 'Electronic_Chime.mp3'
B = 'please_check.mp3'
C = 'three.mp3'

contact_user(A,B,C)
```

And this is the function:

```
def contact_user( A, B, C ):
  ser.write("ATDT441\r")  # Attention - Dial via tone number
  time.sleep(6)

  pygame.mixer.music.load(A)
  pygame.mixer.music.play()
  time.sleep(2)

  pygame.mixer.music.load(B)
  pygame.mixer.music.play(1)
  time.sleep(2)

  pygame.mixer.music.load(C)
  pygame.mixer.music.queue(C)
  pygame.mixer.music.play()

  time.sleep(10)
```

Any ideas or suggestions would be appreciated.

PS. I have tried:

```
thread1 = threading.Thread(contact_user(A,B,C))
thread1.start()
```

The program seems to behave exactly the same even though I have threaded `contact_user(A,B,C)`.

Comment: I'm not familiar with what you're trying to do, but I can tell you that your last bit of code tries to call `threading.Thread` with a target function equal to the **RETURN VALUE** of `contact_user(A, B, C)`. Instead do `thread1 = threading.Thread(lambda: contact_user(A,B,C))` or use `functools.partial` to build the function (e.g. `thread1 = threading.Thread(partial(contact_user, A, B, C))`)

Comment: Are you saying my main program might be waiting on a value to be returned before proceeding? Also, why lambda: and partial?

Comment: @AdamSmith: you should post it as an answer. Though the thread call is still incorrect. See my comment below.

Comment: @user72055: `f()` in Python calls function `f`. To defer calling the function to another thread, use `Thread(target=contact_user, args=[A,B,C])` instead. Also, you should avoid using `time.sleep()` in the same function with other `pygame` calls, schedule an action instead (event-driven approach).

Comment: e.g., instead of sleeping `2` seconds after `load(A); play()` you  could call stop `A` in 2 seconds (on [timer event](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/time.html#pygame.time.set_timer)), here's [code example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17225396/4279)

Comment: I understand my errors, thank you, and I will try to implement a solution this morning. I will report back after trying all the above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My main issue was that I wasn't passing my arguments to my thread properly. Following is the code that worked properly for me.

My function:

```
def contact_user(A,B,C):
  ser.write("ATDT411\r")  # Attention - Dial Tone 411
  time.sleep(5)  # Wait for modem to finish dialing
  pygame.mixer.music.load(A)
  pygame.mixer.music.play()  # Play attention chime
  time.sleep(2)  # Wait long enough for first message chime to play before moving on
  pygame.mixer.music.load(B)
  pygame.mixer.music.play(1) # Play next message
  time.sleep(2)  # Wait long enough for second message to play before moving on
  pygame.mixer.music.load(C) # Load last message
  pygame.mixer.music.queue(C)  # Queue second instance of last message
  pygame.mixer.music.play()  # Play last message twice
  time.sleep(10)  # Wait long enough for last message to play
  ser.write("ATH\r")  # Attention - Hang up line
  ser.write("ATZ\r")  # Attention - Reset modem
  ser.close()
```

Calling function from main program:

```
t = threading.Thread(name = 'dial', target = contact_user, args = (A,B,C))
t.start()
```

Thank you to everyone that helped me with this. Very appreciated.